# Clear React Widget DropdownList if not select any item

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form

I'm using React Widgets for the Dropdown List, I want to customize the onChange to get my state as the selected value:

```
const { selected } = this.state;

return <DropdownList {...rest}
  data={fitData} onSearch={this.search}
  onChange={this.change}
  />
```

The onChange simply like this:

```
change(selected) {
    this.setState({selected});
}
```

It works, but when I close the dropdown list without selecting any value, the `selected` still chosen. What could I do to remove the selected if I don't choose any value?

Answer (score 0):

The onChange event will get called only on a value change.

if you want to listen to the 'closed without selecting' You should listen to the onToggle event.

You can call the same method as you did on the onChange and check the selected value is null/undefined.

```
onToggle={this.change}
```